# Send only one refresh JWT request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jwt, token, refresh

I would like do refresh token before send correct request but I have problem that my react app send a 2-5 requests in 1 view. In this way I send too 2-5 requests to refresh token.

How do I stop all requests before I get an response from refresh?

My code:

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(config => {
    const decoded = decodeJWT(window.localStorage.getItem("jwt"));

    if (decoded && Date.now() >= decoded.exp * 1000) {

      return axiosInstance
        .post("auth/jwt/refresh/", {
          refresh: window.localStorage.getItem("refresh")
        })
        .then(response => {
          window.localStorage.setItem("jwt", response.data.access);
          config.headers.Authorization = `JWT ${response.data.access}`;
          return config;
        })
        .catch(err => {
          window.localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
          return config;
        });
    } else {
      return config;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use locking. For a browser, it's tricky because you also need to take care of locking across tabs. Check out this library I wrote for locking in a browser: https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-tabs-lock

If you want to know how it's to be used, you can see how a library called SuperTokens synchronises calls to refresh APIs: https://github.com/supertokens/supertokens-website/blob/master/handleSessionExp.ts (line no 18-55 are inside a lock).

Hope this helps